# Libgdx - strange behavior of two Actors(hero and coins) after they collide

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-physics

I'm currently creating an 2d infinite runner game. In my game, I have Two actors , the Hero and a Coins, both of their body's are set to dynamic, but everytime the Hero hits/collides the coins, the hero moved to left(the hero's get affected by the coins).

Here's my code, i dont know if whats wrong in my settings, Any help, will be appreciated.

```
public static Body createRunner(World world) {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();

        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(Constants.RUNNER_X, Constants.RUNNER_Y));
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(Constants.RUNNER_WIDTH / 2, Constants.RUNNER_HEIGHT / 2);
        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.setGravityScale(Constants.RUNNER_GRAVITY_SCALE);    
        body.setUserData(new RunnerUserData());  
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.0f; 
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f; 
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        body.resetMassData();
        body.setUserData(new RunnerUserData(Constants.RUNNER_WIDTH, Constants.RUNNER_HEIGHT));


        shape.dispose();
        return body;
    }

    public static Body createCoins(World world) {
        EnemyType enemyType = RandomUtils.getRandomEnemyType();
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        //bodyDef used to set the enemy to make it not be affected when the runner hit
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(enemyType.getX(), enemyType.getY()));
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(enemyType.getWidth() / 2, enemyType.getHeight() / 2);
        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = -100.0f; 
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = -50.0f; 
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        body.resetMassData();
        EnemyUserData userData = new EnemyUserData(enemyType.getWidth(), enemyType.getHeight(), enemyType.getRegions());
        body.setUserData(userData);
        shape.dispose();
        return body;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd set the [ContactFilter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ContactFilter.html) to your world instance via [world.setContactFilter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World.html#setContactFilter-com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ContactFilter-)

This will give you a callback whenever you fixtures collide.  Should you return false from this callback it should prevent Box2D from resolving your collision, which is likely what's pushing your hero left.

```
ContactListener listener = new ContactListneer(){
    public boolean shouldCollide(Fixture fixtureA,
                  Fixture fixtureB){
        Body bodyA = fixtureA.getBody();
        Body bodyB = fixtureB.getBody();
        /* !!! You'll need to implement this next part !!!*/
        //figure out which body is hero, which body is coin
        //if this is a collision between a hero and coin....
        {
            world.destroyBody(coinBody);
            return false;
        }
        //else
            return true;
    }
};
world.setContactFilter(contactFilter);
```

Comment: can you guide me on this sir?, i implemented the ContactListener on my class and determined which bodytype should collide but, the coins keep on pushing the hero, here's my code

Comment: @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

     Body a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
        Body b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

        if ((BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsCoins(b)) ) {
         // runner.hit(); 
        coins.remove();
           world.destroyBody(b);
            
        } else if ((BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(b)) ||
                (BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(b))) {
            runner.landed();
        }

    }

Comment: Sorry for being noob, but i really dont know where should i put world.setContactfilter()